# JS return a link to the page with certain ID in it

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for JavaScript to find the page that an ID is on and return a link to that page?

For example, if I had a  paragraph tag with id="test" on a page called test.html could I get a JavaScript variable to be set to a link to test.html because it has an id="test" on it.

I have probably explained this really badly but I was just wondering if it was possible.

Thanks.

Example of code on test.html

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? For example, what do you mean by "tag". Do you have an example HTML code that you can provide?

Comment: do you need to search among multiple pages simultaneously ?

Comment: If possible @RomanPerekhrest . If not it's not important.

Comment: Where pages are stored?

Comment: @MrOnlineCoder pages are stored in an html folder

Comment: @cCe.jbc, you are dealing with different contexts. You can't parse files in html folder with pure javascript. Consider using PHP in such case and add tag `php` to your question. Otherwise, you can define if tag with `id='test'` exists within current page

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect but I have found a way (kind of) to do this.

HTML:

```
<input id="tosearch" type="text">
<button id="search" type="button" onclick="getsearch()">Search IDs</button>
<p id="searchout"></p>

<script src="search.js">
</script>

<p hidden id=".id">examplepage.html</p>
<p hidden id=".id2">examplepage2.html</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getsearch() {
var search = document.getElementById("tosearch").value;
search = "." + search;

var page = document.getElementById(search).innerHTML;
page = page.link(page);
document.getElementById("searchout").innerHTML = page;
}
```

This allows you to search for an id and returns a link to the page with the id but you have to manually put all the ids and links in.